# what is the wrong with this spec and controller code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test an existing rails project with rspec. And I want to test a controller but getting an error which I can't solve :S

Here is the my spec code ;

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BriefNotesController do

  before(:all) do
    @customer=Factory(:customer)
    @project=Factory(:project_started, :owner => @customer)
  end

  context 'get :new' do

    it 'should redirect to login page for not signed in users' do
      get :new, :project_id => @project.id
      response.should redirect_to("/kullanici-girisi")
    end

    it 'should be success and render new brief note page for project owner' do
      sign_in @customer
      get :new, :project_id => @project.id
      response.should be_success
    end

  end

end
```

Here is the my controller code ;

```
class BriefNotesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :find_project

  def new
    @brief_note = @project.brief_notes.new
  end

  def create
    @brief_note = @project.brief_notes.build(params[:brief_note])
    if @brief_note.save
      redirect_to brief_project_path(@project)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

private
  def find_project
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by_cached_slug([params[:project_id]])
  end
end
```

I think current_user.projects.find_by_cached_slug method don't work. So this is the error;

```
Failures:

  1) BriefNotesController get :new should be success and render new brief note page for         project owner
 Failure/Error: get :new, :project_id => @project.id
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `brief_notes' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/brief_notes_controller.rb:6:in `new'
 # ./spec/controllers/brief_notes_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Are you using an old version of FactoryGirl?

Comment: group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.11.0"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end so no version declared

Comment: I think the [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) syntax is wrong. But I don't see how that could result in your error.

Comment: I believe it should be `FactoryGirl.create(:customer)` instead of `Factory(:customer)`. But I'm not sure, perhaps it's only deprecated and not yet invalid code.

Comment: Also, I can't find out where `find_by_cached_slug` comes from, is the method provided by a gem? Sorry for the comment spam by the way...

Comment: u are wrong. there are no factory girl syntax error. I can access created project object from spec code like this; puts @project.id

Comment: im newbie on rails and i can't found it too :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16061/discussion-between-jugglinghobo-and-user1609468)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for certain without more information about your models, but a likely culprit is that you're passing @project.id as the request parameter, but you're doing the lookup by cached_slug. Try @project.to_param instead.

Comment: fair enough--I wasn't judging you, just suggesting a possible fix for your test! if it wasn't clear, I mean that you should change `get :new, :project_id => @project.id` to `get :new, :project_id => @project.to_param`

Comment: thanks a lot :) your suggestion is totally true for my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your `find_project` filter: `find_by_cached_slug` is returning a nil, which is assigned to `@project`, and that triggers the undefined method error when `brief_notes` is called on it (in the `new` action).

From your spec description I assume that it shouldn't even be executing the `new` code, and instead redirecting in `authenticate_user!`? I don't use devise myself (this is a devise method, right?) so I'm not sure of the specifics of that method, but I think that's where your problem is coming from.

I don't think the problem is your FactoryGirl syntax, which is deprecated but should still work.

Comment: authenticate_user! dont redirect user if he is a customer.